# Visualizing the Complex Product Rule

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

The product rule states that

$$
(fg)' = f'g + fg'
$$

for functions $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

The following picture is frequently given as a way to visualize the *real* product rule (when, i.e., the codomain of $f$,$g$ both happen to be $\mathbb{R}$:

> [image: ]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2wwC.png)

**Question:** Is there a way to visualize the product rule in the strictly *complex* case?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

If I had to demonstrate the  $$
(fg)' = f'g + fg'
$$ rule in the complex case then I would do the following:

Let $f=a+ib$ and $g=e+if$.

Then

$$fg=(a+ib)(e+if)=ae+iaf+ieb-bf.$$

Then I would point at the rule we are used to in the real case. If one differentiates the function above then the one would get exactly $f'g+fg'$.

I cannot imagine any other way to use the OP's figure.